# write file process stop due to window 260 character limit

Tags: php, file, fwrite

for writing i using below code this is very nice and simple work great now i have problem with this we already know that in window 260 character allow for file name problem start from here in code there is option if file not write  stop and terminate process (or die("can't open file");) now i want simple if some reason file not write show echo not write and process continue.I try it myslef but it gives me error

my write function

```
function write($post, $myFile){
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
  fwrite($fh, $post);
  fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: I can't really understand what you're saying. What error do you get?

Comment: I am unable to parse *"now i want simple if some reason file not write show echo not write and process continue.I try it myslef but it gives me error"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a limit on the length of something then you could always check the length of the thing beforehand, and if you don't want your code to exit, then don't use `die()`.

```
function write($post,$myFile){
  if( strlen($myfile) > 260 ) {
    echo "Filename too long";
    return false;
  } else {
    if( ! $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') ) {
      echo "can't open file";
      return false;
    }
    fwrite($fh, $post);
    fclose($fh);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: work but not useful because it stops on error not continues process

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
function write($post,$myFile)
{
   $fh = @fopen($myFile, 'a+');
   if($fh)
   { 
   fwrite($fh, $post);
   fclose($fh);
   }
   else
   {
   echo "can't open file";
   }
}
```